# custom sort function in python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list of lists in python based on certain criteria:

The comparison can be written as:

```
def cmp(item1, item2):
    """
    item1 and item 2 would be lists
    """
    # Second field is equal, compare on first field
    if item1[0][2] == item2[0][2]:
        if item1[0][1] > item2[0][1]:    
            return 1
        elif item1[0][1] == item2[0][1]:     
            return 0
        else:
            return -1
    else:  # Compare on second field
        if item1[0][2] > item2[0][2]:    
           return 1
        elif item1[0][2] == item2[0][2]:     
            return 0
        else:
            return -1
```

In python 3, there is a `key` parameter that can be used for sorting. I wonder how I can specify this function to be used for sorting like python 2.x versions.

Comment: There is also a key parameter in python2, are you asking how to do cmp in python3? i.e  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, I did not word it very clearly.

Comment: Then ^^ functools.cmp_to_key will do the job

Comment: this seems the key function `lambda item: return (item[0][2], item[0][1])` would do the trick ...

Comment: Why do you want to use cmp-based sorting? Looks like you can easily do key-based sorting there, no?

Comment: @StefanPochmann The key based stuff I could not figure out how to write it as a lambda because I have this first check for equality and the control paths based on that..

Comment: @luca you want to first compare elements based on `item[0][2]` then if they are the same compare based on `item[0][1]`, tuples have comparison set up so it compares the first element and if they are equal it then checks the next etc. so using the key function suggested by @mgilson would do exactly what you want in this case.